# Question about ability to make a matrix's determinant 0

Tags: matrices, determinant

The question is as follows:

Given a natural number n, what is the maximum value of the natural number k in terms of n, such that for any arbitrary placement of random k real values on an n by n matrix, there must exist a combination of real numbers to fill the remaining entries so that the determinant will be 0?

So basically, what is the worst case scenario for any given random matrix if we need to make its determinant 0?

Another scenario for the same question is that assume two persons, A and B, are arranging an n by n matrix. First A will fill the matrix, and then B. A's goal is to prevent the matrix's determinant from being 0, and B's goal is to make it 0. A will fill any k entries on the matrix with any real values he wants. What is the biggest value for k such that B can still make the determinant 0 by filling the rest of the matrix with appropriate real numbers? Or in other words, what is the biggest value for k such that A canNOT guarantee that the matrix will have a non-zero determinant?

In case it is not clear, an example for n=2 is k cannot be 4, because obviously some combination of 4 entries will result in non-zero determinant. For k=3, there is this possibility:

```
[1 x]
[0 2]
```

that the determinant will always be 2 for any x. So this is also not a desired k. [Edited->] For k=2, no matter what those given two numbers and their positions on the matrix are, we can fill the rest of the matrix with some values (i.e all zeros) such that the determinant will be 0. So, for n=2, biggest possible k is 2.

For n=1, clearly k is 0 and obviously k is always smaller than n^2.

Appearantly, k must increase as n increases but I don't have a proof of it. If someone solves the question, I'm sure it will be easy to deduce that too.

Comment: One way to approach a lower bound -- how many $k$ can you put in guaranteeing there will be a row or a column of zeroes?

Comment: Your example, suitably generalized actually gives away the answer.  Nice problem!

Comment: For $n=2$, $k=2$, you haven't considered $k=2$.

Comment: Yeah I didn't consider it. It was too late at night I guess :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$k=n(n-1)$ 
$$$$
The determinant of the matrix will be zero iff the column vectors of the matrix are linearly dependent, call these column vectors $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$
If given $n(n-1)$ entries, the idea is to choose the remaining n entries so as to make the columns vectors linearly dependent. (Try to prove you can always do this!)
$$$$
Finally, for $k= n(n-1)+1$ consider an $n$ x $n$ unit matrix and remove the zeros in the first row and leave them blank. No matter how you change the (n-1) blank entries, the value of the determinant will be 1 hence nonzero. Hence $n(n-1)$ is the maximum such $k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Inserting zeroes seems to be a valid option to make the determinant zero. Skipping the k=2 possibility for n=2 mislead me terribly. Appearantly, this problem reduces to this one:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306044/the-possible-number-of-zero-entries-in-n-times-n-matrix-that-would-make-the-de

But since I mislead myself, I failed to notice the similarity between those two problems even though I saw it before posting my question.

Comment: Well even though this problem is similar to the problem in the link, they are not the same; they have opposite purposes to make the determinant zero or non-zero. I understood the solution from your first paragraph but your second paragraph didn't make sense to me.

Comment: The first paragraph shows that if you have n(n-1) entries then you can make the determinant zero. The second paragraph is a counterexample for the case when k>n(n-1). hence making n(n-1) the maximum such value.

Comment: Ok I read it again and it makes sense now. However, think about this, you have a unit matrix with diagonal entries 1, all the upper-diagonal entries 0, (this takes n*(n-1)/2 entries filled in total) and all the lower-diagonal entries are left blank. Since it is an upper diagonal matrix, the determinant is the product of entries on the diagonal which is 1, and no matter how you choose the lower diagonal entries you can't make it 0. Am I wrong? If not, then you can ensure that the determinant will be non-zero only with n*(n-1)/2 entries. According to the n^2-n answer this should not be the case.